# Classify up to isomorphism the groups of order $203$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory, groups-enumeration

> Classify up to isomorphism the groups of order $203$. Assume the face that the least $ k \geq 1$ such that
>
> $$2^k \equiv 1 \mod{29}$$
>
> is $k = 28$. [HINT: Look at the Sylow subgroups and represent a group $G$ of order $203$ as a semi-direct product of two cyclic groups.]

I know that $203 = 7 \cdot 29$. To find my Sylow subgroups I want

$$P = n_7: n_7 \equiv 1 \mod 7 \hspace{1.5cm} n_7\mid 29$$
$$Q = n_{29}: n_{29} \equiv 1 \mod{29} \hspace{1.5cm} n_{29} \mid 7$$

From the hint, we see that $2^k > 203$ and so the only possibility for $n_{29} = 1$. Writing out all the elements for $n_7$, we see that there are two possibilities $n_7 = 1$ or $29$.

Because there's two possibilites for $n_7$, I'm now stuck on what to do. I know that $Q$ is a normal subgroup and so would if I let $P_1 = n_7 = 1$ and $P_2 = n_7 = 29$, would I have to workout the semidirect products such that $Q \rightarrow \mathrm{Aut}(P_1)$ and $Q \rightarrow \mathrm{Aut}(P_2)$?

EDIT: The reason I'm doing the SDP from $Q$ is because I thought in order to calculate it, you need to go from the normal subgroup to the other subgroup. If both are normal, then it shouldn't make any difference (I think),

Comment: When $n_7=1$, you are in the situation of your [last question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/273499/show-that-every-group-g-of-order-175-is-abelian-and-list-all-isomorphism-typ/273506#273506). Judging from the hint you were given, it is entirely possible for $n_7=28$ as well for some nonabelian group, so you'll need to construct one with the SDP.

Comment: How can $n_7 = 28$? Don't you mean $29$?. So as I was in the same bit, I can do that formula DonAntonio gave? Is the question asking me to write down all the SDP's again?

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry, that was a typo :) 29 is right! The question is asking you to give all possible different shapes of groups of that order. One of the shapes is going to be the abelian group of order 203 (you should see there is only one!) but there is apparently another nonabelian group of that order which you can construct with a SDP.

Answer (score 1):

Well, since $\,n_{29}=1\,$ we already know $\,Q\triangleleft G\,$ . As $\,\operatorname{Aut}(Q)\cong C_{28}\,$ , we have two options for a homomorphism $\,P\to\operatorname{Aut}(Q)\,$ : either the trivial one, getting thus the direct product $\,Q\times P\,$ , which is then the cyclic (and abelian, of course) group $\,C_{29}\times C_8\cong C_{203}\,$ ,  or else an embedding $\,P\to\operatorname{Aut}(Q)\,$ , getting a non-direct SDP, and thus non abelian group, $\,Q\rtimes P\,$ ...

Comment: There are 6 nontrivial homomorphisms $P \to {\rm Aut}(Q)$, but the resulting semidirect products are all isomorphic groups (and Kaish needs to prove that).

Answer (score 1):

I will write a detailed answer. You have concluded that $n_{29}=1$. Because Sylow p-groups are conjugate this means $P\lhd G$ ( indeed $gPg^{-1}=P'=P$ because $|gPg^{-1}|=|P|$ so it is also a p-Sylow group. The counting argument follow from the fact that conjugation $\Phi_g$ is an automorphism, hence injective).

Take $Q\in \text{Syl}_7(G)$ Because $P\lhd G$, we know $PQ$ is a group. Furthermore if $g\in P\cap Q\Rightarrow |g||7$ and $|g||29$. So $g=1$ and we have a trivial intersection. This means we have a semidirect product. The thing is $|PQ|=pq$ so in fact $G=P\rtimes Q$.

Okay, so as you pointed out we need to study $\theta:Q\rightarrow\text{Aut}(P)$. We only need to define it in a generator $\langle u\rangle=Q$, because that will teach us $\theta(u^j)$ for any $j$. But we need to make sure $\theta(u^{7})=I$ so that this is a valid automorphism.

Simillarly, we can specify $\theta(u)(v)$ to determine $\theta(u)$ uniquely if $\langle v \rangle=Q$. But, once more, so that we do not reach contradictions we need $\theta(u)(v^{29})=1$. Fair enough. What do we know so far? We need to choose $j$ with $1 \leq j < 29$ (we do not want $j=29$ because that would not be an automorphism) such that:

$$\theta(u)(v)=v^j \Rightarrow \theta(u)(v^{29})=v^{29j}=(v^{29})^j=1^j=1$$

So our first condition is a takeaway. We still need to make sure $\theta(u^{7})$ is the identity:

$$v=\theta(u^{7})(v)=\theta(u^{6})(v^j)=\theta(u^{5})((v^j)^j)=...=v^{j^{7}}$$

Okay, so this will hold if and only if $|v|=29|j^{7}-1$. So we need to solve $j^{7}\equiv 1 \mod 29$ for $1 \leq j<29$.

$j=1$ clearly satisifies our condition and in that case $\theta(u)=I$ and we have the direct (abelian) product $Q\times P\approx \mathbb{Z}_{29}\times \mathbb{Z}_7$.

When $j>1$, we need that its order divides $29-1=28$ by Fermat's Little Theorem and we also need it to divide $7$. Because the order is not $1$ it must be $7$ and $7|28$ as requested. Okay. How many such $j$ are there?

Well, because $\mathbb{Z}_{29}^*$ is cyclic there is a unique cyclic subgroup of order $7$. Thus there are $\Phi(7)=6$ generators and $6$ values of $j$ which yield valid automorphisms. These are all isomorphic as we will show.

However, before we start let me note that if the order of these $j$ is $7$, the first time we have $v^{j^k}$ being equal to $v$ is when $k=7$. Because these will all be different values then $\theta$ is injective.

(They are different because if $v^{j^{k_1}}=v^{j^{k_2}}$, we would have $|v|=29|j^{k_1}-j^{k_2}$, so $j^{k_1}\equiv j^{k_2}\mod 29$ and $j^{k_1-k_2}\equiv 1 \mod 29$, so $|j|=7|k_1-k_2$ so $k_1=k_2+7t$, but all $k_1$ and $k_2$ are $1 \leq k\leq 7$ so we must have $t=0$)

Take $j_1$ (defining $\theta_1$) and $j_2$ (defining $\theta_2$). Because we are in a cyclic subgroups and our $j_s$ generate it we must have $j_2=j_1^{z_1}$:

$$\theta_2(u)(v)=v^{j_2}=v^{j_1^{z_1}}=\theta_1(u^{z_1})(v).$$

Let us define $\Psi: P\rtimes_{\theta_2}Q\rightarrow P\rtimes_{\theta_1}Q$ by $\Psi(x,y)=(x,y^{z_1})$. In this case:

$$\Psi\left((x,y)(z,w)\right)=\Psi(x\theta_{2}(y)(z),yw)=(x\theta_1(y^{z_1})(z),(yw)^{z_1})$$
$$=(x\theta_1(y^{z_1})(z),y^{z_1}w^{z_1})=(x,y^{z_1})(z,w^{z_1})=\Psi(x,y)\Psi(z,w)$$

So we have a homomorphism and an identical computation with $j_1=j_2^{z_2}$ shows we are able to define a new homomorphism $\tilde{\Psi}:P\rtimes_{\theta_1}Q\rightarrow P\rtimes_{\theta_2}Q$ with $\tilde{\Psi}(x,y)=(x,y^{z_2})$.

If we take $\Psi \circ \tilde{\Psi} (x,y)=(x,y^{z_1z_2})$ we have:
$$\theta_2(u)=\theta_1(u^{z_1})=\theta_1(u)^{z_1}=\theta_2(u^{z_2})^{z_1}=\theta_2(u^{z_1z_2})$$

So $u^{z_1z_2}=u$ (as we remarked any $\theta$ is injective) and $\Psi \tilde{\Psi} (x,y)=(x,y^{z_1z_2})=(x,y)$. So we really have an isomorphism and all of those other groups when $j\not=1$ are isomorphic.