# Show that a group of order $175$ is not simple.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory, p-groups, simple-groups

$|G| = 175 = 5^2 \times 7$
After small calculation I found that only possible value of $n_5 = 1$ and $n_7 = 1$.
How to prove that $G$ is not simple group?

Comment: Let $P$ be a $p$-Sylow subgroup of $G$ and let $g \in G$.  Then $\forall g \in G ~g^{-1}Pg$ must also be a $p$-Sylow subgroup of $G$.  What conclusion can you draw about $P$ from that fact that $G$ has a unique $p$-Sylow subgroup?

Comment: The cyclic group of order $175$ is not simple. (I am answering the question literally.)

Comment: Every such group is [abelian](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/273499/show-that-every-group-g-of-order-175-is-abelian-and-list-all-isomorphism-typ?rq=1).

Answer (score 1):

Let $|G| = 175$. You've correctly calculated that $n_5 = 1$ and $n_7 = 1$. Since there is only one Sylow-$25$ subgroup and only one Sylow-$7$ subgroup - both these Sylow subgroups **must be normal subgroups** of $G$.

Since we have shown the existence of non-trivial normal subgroups, $G$ is not simple.

The following theorem ([proof here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2501579/why-is-a-unique-sylow-p-subgroup-normal/2501582)) will help:

> A Sylow $p$-subgroup is unique if and only if it is a normal subgroup.

Answer (score 1):

You proved it is not simple,  because you found a nontrivial normal subgroup.

Here's an alternate.   By Burnside's theorem the group is solvable.   If it's non-abelian it can't be simple.

On the other hand if it's abelian and simple its order would have to be prime.

Comment: And certainly it *is* abelian, see above.